# Item URL in {{var items}} is going to url without ".html" extension so Error is showing No CMS Page Found

Tags: magento-1.7, email-templates

We have installed [this extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-cart.html) and in email template Item URL in {{var items}} is not going to Correct Item URL

It is going to "www.mydomain.com/item-url", not "www.mydomain.com/item-url.html"

Due to this it is Showing Error There was no 404 CMS page configured or found.

How to Debug/Solve this?

This is our email template

```
<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
        <!-- [ header starts here] -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Dear Customer,</h1>
                <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">

                    We noticed you didn't complete the checkout process and your items were left in the cart.<br><br>
                    If you are having trouble placing your order and need help, please reply to this email
                    and we will assist you as soon as possible or feel free to call us on 18000000.
                    You can check the items in your Cart by <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">logging into your account</a>.
                </p>

        </tr>
        <tr>
                    <td>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px" style="border: 1px solid rgb(206,206,206);background:rgb(244,244,244);width: 100%;">
                        <tr style="background:rgb(229,229,229);">
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Item</td>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Sku</td>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Qty</td>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Subtotal</td>
                        </tr>

                        {{var items}}

                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>


        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you, <strong>{{var store.getFrontendName()}}</strong></p></center></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For forcing a "cms page url" to open using ".html" extension (www.mydomain.com/item-url.html)

You need to create a rewrite rule in magento admin panel.

Please go to Catalog> Url Rewrite Management> Add Url Rewrite.

1. "Create URL Rewrite:" dropdown choose "custom"
2. "Store *": Choose your store
3. ID Path *: "custom cms page" (itc could be any name)
4. Request Path *: www.mydomain.com/item-url.html
5. Target Path *:www.mydomain.com/item-url
6. Redirect: No

"save" it.

Now, run www.mydomain.com/item-url.html url, it will not give 404 page error.

Cheere!!

Comment: Praveen, Its not a cms page, Its a product URL